# How do I fix the warning about "conflicting distribution" when doing apt update after installing MKL?

Tags: apt, intel, software-sources, binary

After installing MKL using instructions from [Intel's documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installing-intel-free-libs-and-python-apt-repo), when I do a

```
sudo apt update
```

It throws a warning:

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: Conflicting distribution: https://apt.repos.intel.com/intelpython binary/ InRelease (expected binary/ but got )
```

Comment: It's a different problem, the package for the conflicting distribution is MKL here, it's plex in the suggested duplicate question.

Comment: Both questions have the same pattern except that there is a different URL in the error message, so follow the logic in the answer except replace old-URL with new-URL. Otherwise we would need to have a new question for every single unique URL, because there would be no permissible pattern except for identically matching the entire string character for character including the URL.